# Thread Safety in File I/O

Tags: python, thread-safety

I have a class which contains methods for read and write data into a file. It also has methods for opening and closing the file. How can I make the read and write operations thread safe in Python? i.e. if a write operation is under progress, it should block all other threads until it has finished the operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [thread lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to limit a section of code to one thread at a time. `.acquire()` a lock, perform the operation you want to be thread safe, then `.release()` the lock. All the threads must share a lock object.